Python Scrapy Import ItemLoader Issue
New to Python and scrapy. maybe you find it silly question :D

from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.item import TakeFirst, MapCompose

No command is working for my project
My scrapy Version: 2.12.0
I tried all the bellow mentioned 3 commands one by one

from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.loader import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.item import TakeFirst, MapCompose


scrapy.loader.processors was deprecated in 2020. You should use newer documentation.

according to the itemloaders documentation you should be using
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose


The mentored import from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose was used for Scrapy version <2.0.
For 2.0+ the correct import is from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose.
In order to have more control on the data and how it's processed my suggestion is to make a pipeline which will be triggered when yield item is invoked.
Example:
# myspider.py    
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
...

def parse(self, response):
        
    prod_name = response.css('h1.title::text').get()
    item = MyItem({
        "name": prod_name
    })
    yield item

In order to use pipelines.py you should enable it in the settings.py.
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'myProject.pipelines.MyPipeline': 300,
}

and for pipelines.py
#pipelines.py

class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        #for example strip empty chars from 'name' item field.
         item['name'] = item.get('name').strip()
         ...

Make sure that you have items.py as well
# items.py example

from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class MyItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = Field()

